# how do i make sure the user put a whole number and not a decimal in c?

Tags: c

I am making a code that calculate the surface area of a polygon. the user must, among others, enter the number of sides to the polygon which cannot be a decimal. I need it to fit into a condition of "if":

```
if (side_a < 0 || radius < 0 ||  diameter < side_a || num_pol<3 ||...
```

the code must mean: "if num_pol is decimal"

also I must calculate the area of a polygon which has a circle in it. the formula is: radius^2 * number of sides * tangent(180/num of sides). so I wrote in C:

```
pow(radius,2)*num_pol*tan(P/(2*num_pol)) //P is pi//
```

is it correct?
thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use: `ceilf(side) == side && side > 0`

Here is the verification code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    double side;
    side = 3.0;
    if(ceilf(side) == side && side > 0)
        printf("true");
    else
        printf("false");
    side = 3.1;
    if(ceilf(side) == side && side > 0)
        printf("true");
    else
        printf("false");
    side = 3.6;
    if(ceilf(side) == side && side > 0)
        printf("true");
    else
        printf("false");
    side = -3.6;
    if(ceilf(side) == side && side > 0)
        printf("true");
    else
        printf("false");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: could you explain further? i didn't understand.

Comment: yeah sure, will be glad to

Comment: But... why storing the number of sides in a `double`?

Comment: It will be needed in his calculations, to avoid extra type casting, as his formula is equating doubles

Comment: it's better to cast a int to a double than having a variable with a datatype that can store invalid values IMHO...

Comment: `cielf` computes the smallest integer value not less than given argument, so numers like 3.1, 3.2, ... are converted to 4.0; which leads to `false` condition. While 3.0 remains same, which leads to `true` condition

Comment: it can be easily checked so not much of a issue IMHO, and a lot of times calculations are long, so typecasting is tiresome

Answer (score 0):

> how do i make sure the user put a whole number and not a decimal in c?

Use an integer type such as `int`.

As for the formula, the best way to know is to test your program with various examples. This advice works for all your programs: test your code before asking someone else to review it.

Comment: i tested it and it seems to work but sometime i dont see the whole picture

Comment: if i use int from the beginning, what happens if the user puts something like : 14.67?

Comment: and if you use a `double`, what happens if the user puts something like : `blah`?

Comment: our assignment says we can assume only numbers will be typed